# How to construct a read-only Dictionary?

Tags: c#, initialization, constants

So, I am designing a global constant which would hold data for different characters for the program. I think `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` is my data type here, as it allows very quick searches by character. The declaration looks like this:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<char, LetterImage> letters;
```

(`LetterImage` being a custom struct. It's contents are not important.)

The problem? How do I define the elements of the `Dictionary`? I cannot just `letters.Add('a', new LetterImage{...})`because the dictionary is `readonly`, as I don't want a global variable. I need a way to initialize it with a literal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the apropriate collection to make sure the dictionary is truly readonly, that is a [ReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx). And you can initialize it inline

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<char, LetterImage> dictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<char, LetterImage>
{
    ['a'] = new LetterImage()
});
```

If you have more complex code to initialize the dictionary, you could also use a static constructor (you can assign readonly fields in a static constructor)

```
class Program
{
    public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<char, LetterImage> dictionary;
    static Program()
    {
        var mutable = new Dictionary<char, LetterImage>();
        // Initalize
        dictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<char, LetterImage>(mutable)
    }
}
```

**Note** the `readonly` modifier does not impact the mutability of the object stored in the field. If you store a normal dictionary in a readonly field, you can still mutate the dictionary, you just can modify the field.

Comment: A verbose thing to do, but probably the best as it does exactly what I want. Thank you.